# Why is ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual(hide.ns = T) not working in my loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, ggpubr

I do a lot of my plotting with loop, since I often need to create the same plots for different measurements/sexes (facet.wrap is not an option).
For statistical significance I create a dataframe like this:

```
emmeans_c<- data_all_c %>% 
  group_by(sex, light_c, measurement) %>%
  emmeans_test(values~group, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")%>%
  add_xy_position( x = "light_c", dodge = 0.9)
```

I then map this via `ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual`. Of course I am only interested in the significant differences, so I use `hide.ns=T`.

```
for(m in unique(data_all_c$measurement)){
  for (s in unique(data_all_c$sex)) {
    const <-  ggplot(subset(data_all_c, sex == s | measurement == m))+ 
                    aes(x = light_c, y = values, fill = group)+
                    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "bar", position = "dodge")+
                        stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),width = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE)+
                    stat_pvalue_manual(subset(emmeans_c, sex == s & measurement == m), 
                                       label = "p.adj.signif", xmin = "xmin", xmax = "xmax", step.group.by = "group1", color = "darkgrey"
                                       ,inherit.aes = FALSE, hide.ns = T
                                       )                                   
    
    print(const)
    }}
```

Works fine if I do every `subset()` by hand, but as soon as the code is in the loop I get the following error message:

```
Error:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'label' not found
Backtrace:
  1. base::print(const)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(const)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 14. ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
 15. ggplot2:::scales_add_defaults(...)
 16. base::lapply(aesthetics[new_aesthetics], eval_tidy, data = data)
 17. rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
Error in (function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "bracket", position = "identity", :

ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'label' not found
```

(with `hide.ns = F` the loop works)

**Does it just not work in a loop or do i have a error somewhere that i don't see? The lable is defined, isn't it?**

*My real data ist much bigger, so here a code of what it looks like:*

```
data_all_c<-rbind(as.data.frame(cbind(rbind(cbind(light_c = c("day", "night", "24h"),sex = "f", group = "A"), 
                                            cbind(light_c = c("day", "night", "24h"),sex = "m", group = "A")),
                                      rbind(
                                            as.data.frame(cbind( measurement = "Flow" ,values = rnorm(50, mean = 5, sd = 0.008))),
                                            as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 23, sd = 1))),
                                            as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Hum", values = rnorm(50, mean = 25, sd = 5)))
                                             ))),
                   as.data.frame(cbind(rbind(cbind(light_c = c("day", "night", "24h"),sex = "f", group = "B"), 
                                             cbind(light_c = c("day", "night", "24h"),sex = "m", group = "B")),
                                       rbind(
                                         as.data.frame(cbind( measurement = "Flow" ,values = rnorm(50, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.01))),
                                         as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 22, sd = 0.8))),
                                         as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Hum", values = rnorm(50, mean = 50, sd = 2)))
                                       ))),
                   as.data.frame(cbind(rbind(cbind(light_c = c("day", "night", "24h"),sex = "f", group = "C"), 
                                             cbind(light_c = c("day", "night", "24h"),sex = "m", group = "C")),
                                       rbind(
                                         as.data.frame(cbind( measurement = "Flow" ,values = rnorm(50, mean = 0.16, sd = 0.002))),
                                         as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Temp",values = rnorm(50, mean = 24, sd = 1.3))),
                                         as.data.frame(cbind(measurement = "Hum", values = rnorm(50, mean = 100, sd = 10)))
                                       ))))
data_all_c$values<-as.numeric(data_all_c$values)
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data (using `dput`) so we can replicate your issue and understand the issue.

Comment: I edit a code which creates a similar but smaller data set

Comment: I think the problems is related to the fact that in some of your groups all of the P's are "ns". I am not knowledgeable enough with `ggpubr` to suggest a solution.